# isotope plugin fails to load properly, and cuts off div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

So if you check out: http://uniplaces.micrositesonline.info/blog/cities/ you'll see the isotope masonry plugin in action. The entire theme is from https://themetrust.com/demos/swell/. The issue is, on our site, the isotope plugin loads in a strange manner, the div that contains the masonry images fails to adjust the height properly and thus, it sometimes gets cut off. You can typically replicate this by reloading the page once it has loaded.

[image]

The code containing the js is in 'themetrust.js':

```
///////////////////////////////
// Project Filtering
///////////////////////////////

function projectFilterInit() {
    if( jQuery('#filter-nav a').length > 0 ) {
        jQuery('#filter-nav a').click(function(){
            var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
            jQuery('#projects.thumbs').isotope({
                filter: selector,
                hiddenStyle : {
                    opacity: 0,
                    scale : 1
                }
            });

            if ( !jQuery(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
                jQuery(this).parents('#filter-nav').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
            }

            return false;
        });
    } // if() - Don't have this element on every page on which we call Isotope
}

///////////////////////////////
// Project thumbs
///////////////////////////////

function isotopeInit() {
    setColumns();
    gridContainer.isotope({
        resizable: true,
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: colW
        }
    });

    jQuery(".thumbs .small").css("visibility", "visible");

}

///////////////////////////////
// Isotope Grid Resize
///////////////////////////////

function setColumns()
{
    var columns;
    var gw = gridContainer.width();
    var ww = jQuery(window).width()
    if(ww<=700){
        columns = 1;
    }else if(ww<=870){
        columns = 2;
    }else{
        columns = 3;
    }
    colW = Math.floor(gw / columns);
    jQuery('.thumbs .small').each(function(id){
        jQuery(this).css('width',colW+'px');
    });
    jQuery('.thumbs .small').show();
}

function gridResize() {
    setColumns();
    gridContainer.isotope({
        resizable: false,
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: colW
        }
    });
}

///////////////////////////////
// Center Home Banner Text
///////////////////////////////

function centerHomeBannerContent() {
    var bannerContent = jQuery('.home #banner-content');
    var bannerContentTop = (windowHeightAdjusted/2) - (jQuery('.home #banner-content').actual('height')/2);
    bannerContent.css('margin-top', bannerContentTop+'px');
    bannerContent.show();
}

///////////////////////////////
// Initialize
///////////////////////////////

jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".content-area").fitVids();
    mmenu_nav();
    jQuery('#video-background').height(windowHeight);
    video_resize();
    if(!isMobile()){
        getVideoBGs();
    }

    jQuery('body').imagesLoaded(function(){
        projectFilterInit();
        isotopeInit();
        centerHomeBannerContent();
    });

    jQuery(window).smartresize(function(){
        gridResize();
        //full_width_images();
        video_resize();
        mmenu_nav();
        centerHomeBannerContent()
    });

    //Set Down Arrow Button
    jQuery('#down-button').click(function(){
        jQuery.scrollTo( ".middle", {easing: 'easeInOutExpo', duration: 1000} );
    });

    //pull_out_the_quote();
    //full_width_images();

});
```

We've tried modifying it to no avail, removing and tweeking, but nothing seems to work. At this point we think it make be the css transition initialized by the class `isotope-item`, so we removed it, which seems to work but we are not entirely sure why. Is it possible to retain the transitions and get the isotope plugin to behave with them reliably?

Comment: Where are your portfolio filters? Why don't you contact theme authors?

Comment: Ok I loaded the site again, and now it works. As DCdaz said, the script just doesn't load all the time. Try minimizing all the scripts in js folder (be careful to enqueue this new scripts file in functions.php, and dequeue old ones). Or use a plugin that will optimize your site (autoptimize, W3 Total Cache)...

Answer (score 1):

WOOOO that theme is mental to say the least.

There are so many HTTP request's it's not surprising it's failing to load some scripts within the exec time.

Right because this is a theme and we don't want to mess about with stuff to much for updating sake's I would recommend using [autoptomize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/)

It will compress and conjoin all your scripts and css files into one nice neat and easy to download file so that no render blocking or partial loading occur's

Comment: hmm weird I will check it again and get back to you

Comment: cant check you have an error in your fucntions file

Answer (score -2):

Just reviewed your site on http://uniplaces.micrositesonline.info/blog/cities/, probably "jquery.isotope.js" file is missing on your directly. Make sure the presence of "jquery.isotope.js" at JS folder. lets try

Comment: The file is present, if you look in the sources -> wp-content>themes/swell>js folder you'll see it's loaded.